# What's wrong with the proof that $1!=0$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, fake-proofs

I found this proof which shows that $1! = 0$ using Taylor Series. Here's what we do:
Start with the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$. We get :
$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \dots$$ Now if we integrate both the sides we get:
$$-\cos(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \frac{x^8}{8!} + \dots$$ So we get that $\cos(x)$ is equal to(By multiplying both sides by $-1$) :
$$\cos(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - \dots$$ Now we'll again integrate both the sides, getting :
$$\sin(x) = -\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} - \dots$$ Now if we re-arrange it, we get :
$$\sin(x) = \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} - \frac{x^{11}}{11!} + \dots$$ Now, we'll do the same thing with $\cos(x)$, getting :
$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots (1)$$ Now, we'll re-arrange $\cos(x)$ too, getting :
$$\cos(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots (2)$$ Now, we know that $(1)=(2)$ So,
$$1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots = -\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots$$ So, we get that $1! = 0$

But, what's wrong with this proof?

Comment: "*If we integrate both sides*"  You forgot your **+C**.  There are a whole class of functions who are antiderivatives of a function, varying by their constant terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 2 is wrong.  That's not the Taylor series for $-\cos x$.

With any functions, including Taylor series, antiderivatives are only defined up to a constant.  So line 2 should read
$$-\cos(x) +C = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \frac{x^8}{8!} + \dots$$
In this case $C=1$, since $\cos(0) = 1$.

The rest of the derivation covers up the basic fact that you are missing a $1$.  So it's not surprising that it leads to $1=0$.

Comment: You should mention that OP forgot the "+c" when integrating.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, you're right about that.  I'll flesh out my answer a bit more.

Comment: I think it's clearer to just take the definite integral from $0$ to $x$ on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)